# Декодирование строк python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой. Приходит ответ со стороннего сервера в виде

```
{"organizations":[{"address":"\xd0\xb3. \xd0\x9c\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0,...}
```

При декодировании в виде :

```
uni = b'\xd0\xb3. \xd0\x9c\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0'.decode('utf')
```

все работает отлично, но, если я записываю эти символы в переменную(строку) и делаю:
`uni.decode('utf')` - выводится строка в таком же виде, как и до декодирования.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Этот вид непонятен, укажите тип переменной, в которой содержится ответ, и как вы этот ответ вообще получаете. А лучше полноценный работающий пример, если это возможно

Comment: часть кода
header = {"token": token, "Content-type": "application/json"}
http = httplib2.Http()
content = http.request("http://юрл", method="GET", headers=header)
print(type(content)) - tuple
в этом кортеже содержится текст, как я описал выше.
проблема в том, что вместо русских букв вот это \xd0\xb3.

Comment: tuple? Это весьма странный тип для HTTP-ответов. Покажите `print(repr(content))`

Comment: print(repr(content))
({'access-control-allow-headers': 'Content-Type, Secret', 'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'access-control-max-age': '1728000', 'connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'content-length': '219', 'content-type': 'ap
plication/json', 'date': 'Thu, 27 Sep 2018 13:45:52 GMT', 'server': '0.2.0', 'status': '200', 'content-location': 'юрл_сервера'}, b'{"organizations":[{"address":"\xd0\xb3. \xd0\x9c\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb","created_at":"2017-08-30 16:13:35","full_name":"te...}

Comment: `content[1].decode('utf-8')` да и всё

Comment: Спасибо огромное, это решило мою проблему. Счастье было очень близко)